# Flash player debugger not working

Tags: eclipse, debugging, flash-builder, flash

I am working in Eclipse Indigo + Flex Builder 4.5 + Maven + Flash player 11 debugger version in Firefox browser + Flex SDK 4.1, and while debugging in Eclipse the launcher sticks at 57% and then error dialog appears:

> The Flash Builder debugger failed to connect to the running application.
>   Ensure that:
>
> 1. For in-browser applications, you are running the debugger version of Flash Player.
> 2. For network debugging on a mobile device, you have a reliable network connection to the device, and port 7935 is open on your machine's firewall.
>          Device connection help

Also, I have tried almost all the available solutions on the net (like reinstall player, html-template folder, project clean, mm.cfg n all), but nothing helps.

Answer (score 0):

Hanging at 57% means that it's failing to connect to the Flash player.

Is your Run/Debug configuration set up to automatically open a page that loads your Flash application?  A custom Run/Debug configuration may require you to take whatever action launches the Flash player/plugin.

If that's not the case, have you tried uninstalling the Flash plugin before installing the debug version?  Sometimes browsers just can't let go, or switch to the standard version after an update.