# The Flash Builder debugger failed to connect to the running application

Tags: flash-builder

I know this has been posted a few times like here:
[Flash player debugger not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8427503/flash-player-debugger-not-working)
but I have uninstalled flash player and tried to reinstall an older version of flash player 10.1 which I believe worked with my 4.5 version of Flash Builder. But I go to 
http://flashplayerversion.com/
and it still says I have mac 12.0.0.44 debugger version installed in Firefox. How can I get the older version of the flash player to install? Is there something I should uninstall to make sure my system installs FP 10.1?

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem of launching the debug version of firefox:
http://www.bryandragon.com/articles/flash-builder-debugging-with-firefox/